# Creating a script involving the memory usage of processes

Tags: scripts, process, memory-usage

How can one create a bash script that displays the sum of memory usage for the processes which have `PID<100`?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
ps -e -o pid,pmem | awk '{  if($1>100) s+=$2} END {print s}'
```